# How to make custom callback in keras to generate sample image in VAE training?

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, generative-models, vae

I'm training a simple VAE model on 64*64 images and I would like to see the images generated after every epoch or every couple batches to see the progress.

when I train the model I wait until the training is done and then I look at the results.

I tried to make a custom callback function in Keras that generates an image and saves it but couldn't do it. is it even possible? I couldn't find anything like it.

it would be awesome if you refer me to a source that explains how to do so or show me an example

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784921/how-to-display-custom-images-in-tensorboard-using-keras?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the two following links could help you [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/image_summaries), [2](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/).

The first one is a tutorial, which introduces you how to display images in TensorBoard.
If you look at the part on the confusion matrix, you should find a way to make your desired callback, i.e. a callback which involves displaying an image.

The second link is also a tutorial that shows you how to write your very own custom callback in TensorFlow with Keras.

I think by combining both tutorial you should have a pretty good idea how to do what you want.